# Integrate product of matrices: $\int_0^t A(t) B A^T(t) dt$.

Tags: matrices, definite-integrals

I have an integral of a product of three $3\times3$ matrices:  $\displaystyle\int_0^t A(t) B A^T(t)\ dt$

Where $B$ is the matrix of zeros with $1$ at $(2,2)$.

But $A(t)$ is incredibly complicated (with 2000+ terms). So I want to leave its computation till the last step. $A(t)$ is actually the matrix exponential of another matrix: $ A(t) = e^{Mt} $

Since these three don't commute, I can't bring all the time dependent matrices at one end and do the integral.

Is there any way I can do this without explicitly writing $A(t)$ ?
Any help will be very appreciated!

Edit: M is not symmetric, but is diagonalisable.

Comment: Is $M$ symmetric? diagonalizable?

Comment: Just to gain intuition, you might try working through with just the first 4-5 terms of $A$. You may end up with a series that is easily identifiable.

Comment: Diagonalizing would make things more complicated given how simple $B$ is. The integrand simplifies to $$\mathbf{a_2\otimes a_2} \equiv a_2a_2^T$$ the outer product of the second column of $A$ with itself.

Comment: Series expansion doesn't go well with B, because of all the nonlinear terms, it doesn't get simplified... The outer product of 2nd column of A with itself is nice. But there's no way to extract this information from M itself. So this still requires writing A=exp(Mt) explicitly.